# What is the Latin word for "manifesto"?

Tags: word-request

If I wanted to speak of the Communist Manifesto or the Humanist Manifesto in Latin, what word should I use? Perhaps "praeconium communisticum", as Wikipedia suggests? If I understand correctly, "manifestum" would be bad Latin. What about "edictum"?

I am interested in the word manifesto itself, but also in a translation of the two specific examples I have given.